# Add Swagger 3 OpenAPI documentation on RequestParams packed into java record

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, java-record

I have a controller below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/client", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Tag(name = "Client")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class PersonController {
    @Operation(summary = "Get client info")
    @GetMapping
    public PersonInfoResponse getPersonInfo(
            @Valid PersonSearchParameters parameters
    ) {
       // some logic
    }
}
```

Search parameters are grouped together inside `PersonSearchParameters` class. Java takes them as query parameters even without annotation `@RequestParam`

```
@ValidPersonSearchParameter // custom validation
public record PersonSearchParameters(
        @Schema(required = true, description = "Search key")
        @NotNull SearchKey searchKey,

        @Schema(required = true, description = "Value")
        @NotBlank String value,

        @Schema(description = "Birthday")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate birthday
) {
}
```

I want to have Schema description right inside the request in Swagger as it is for JSON request body.

[image: image from the internet]

But I only have an example value. By the way, name "parameters" was given automatically even before I specified it.

[image: example value]

And I also can scroll down the page and see documentation on PersonSearchParameters
[image: schema described separately]

Do you know how to put them together? My try was like that, but it didn't help:

```
@Parameters({
        @Parameter(name = "parameters", description = "Search parameters", required = true,
                schema = @Schema(implementation = PersonSearchParameters.class))
})
public PersonInfoResponse getPersonInfo(
        @Valid @RequestParam("parameters") PersonSearchParameters parameters
```

Here I added `@Parameters` description on my controller method and `@RequestParam("parameters")` on the argument. I hoped that `schema = @Schema...` would help, but it didn't. Any ideas?